# Creating Wallet Address with coinbase API Using Axios Request

Tags: node.js, axios, coinbase-api

Hello I'm trying to use the coinase api using axios to make request. I have set up the neccessary api authentication using SHA256 HMAC. I have been able to make some GET Request and got response. I have been trying to make a POST Request but i have been getting 401 status code.

````
    const name = "Test BTC Address";
    const body = {
      name: name
    }
    var encHash = {
      baseUrl: 'https://api.coinbase.com',
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/v2/accounts/bbc2e3f7-a851-50ab-b4b3-a0f2a700846f/addresses',
      body: body,
      scopes: "wallet:addresses:create"
    };
      const sign = generateHashKey(encHash, key.APISECRET);
      console.log(sign);
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': sign.signature,
          'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': sign.timestamp,
          'CB-ACCESS-KEY': key.APIKEY,
          'CB-VERSION': '2021-10-15'
        }
      }
      
      const url = `${encHash.baseUrl}${encHash.path}`
      console.log(url);
      var options = await axios.post(url, body, config); 
      return res.send({data: options.data})
  } catch (error) {
      // console.error(error);
      return res.send({error})
  } ```
````

Comment: Is the json message ‘Invalid signature’? That sign doesn’t look right to me

Comment: No it's 401 Unauthorised